# Identify work items included in a release from chained builds

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to extend the list of associated build work items with those of the triggering build?

We have build pipelines set-up like this:

```
Components
- Component #1
- Component #2

Assemblies
- Assembly #1 (depends on Component #1)
- Assembly #2 (depends on Component #1 and Component #2)
```

A successful build of a Component triggers the associated Assembly build, for example:

- Component #1 builds successfully > Triggers Assembly #1 build
- Component #2 builds successfully > Triggers Assembly #1 and Assembly #2 build

I know that a release of an Assembly will track associated Assembly work items (through commits). I need a way to track a Component work item up to it's release through an Assembly.

Comment: You can refer to this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-GenerateReleaseNotes-Task&targetId=b4f49e36-84e5-48a6-b338-51f8ecc1d8d7) to see if it helps.

Comment: I have no doubt I can manage to put something together using the API.
If DevOps can't do it, I'll definitely look into it.